# JPA OneToOne relationship to two different types

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, orm

I'm using Hibernate JPA implementation to map a relational database to my model objects.

Please see the simplified diagram:

[image]

In my application, I need one customer to have one implant or one prosthesis at a time, not both is possible. I would like to have only one field in my Customer model to link the Prosthesis or the Implant, that would be great, but I didn't figured out how..

For now, I'm thinking of not using any relation mapping, and setting Customer fields like:

- field "type" : Implant or Prosthesis
- field "prosthesis" : nullable
- field "implant": nullable

And performing, based on type's value, a JPQL query to get a DTO (syntax `new my.package.dto.Prosthesis(...) from Prosthesis` if the type is Prosthesis, and so on for Implant).

Except if you prove I'm wrong, I'm afraid a relation mapping could try a join between Customer table and Prosthesis table even if the Customer's type is Implant for example. I would like to avoid that unnecessary query.

Any optimisation proposition among SO community ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I also think that mapping a relationship will be handled with JOIN, but I think that @OneToOne relationships, as your model implies, are fast enough as they match the ID for the join.

Comment: @Guillem yes, but it will result in two fieds with @ OneToOne relationship, which will execute two joined queries. Maybe if I put LAZY on both of them? I'm gonna test

Comment: I think LAZY would only work for OneToMany or ManyToMany in order to "delay" the fetch until the moment when you call the variable, but not for OneToOne. Anyway, in my experience fetching OneToOne relationships is fast, as it uses the JPA Id primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If your table implant and prosthesis are not simplified you could merge them, if you don't mind having a null value. So that in your customer table you have only one field linking to either prosthesis or implant ensuring having only one type at a time. Then your genericWordAboutImplantAndProsthesis table would look like :

- genericWordAboutImplantAndProsthesisId
- brand
- model
- productionDate
- powered(null)
- location(null)

You can add a field type as you mentioned or deduce it depending on which field (powered or location) isn't null.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that already, thanks for suggestion, unfortunately, there is more fields specific for each class here, so I think abstraction may not be a good idea as I would like to put some database constraints on them.